# Odd behaviour of defaulting to previous assignment if string is left blank by user input [Solved]

Tags: arrays, c, string, variables, memory

I have a function which replaces a particular word/line/phrase in a file.

Using the below, I have allowed the user to ' *remove* ' or 'replace with *nothing* ' by simply pressing the ENTER key upon encountering the '`Replacement :` ' prompt.

I expect it to work, since this action of the user appears to return a string of length `0`, which is the condition I can test and then basically assign `\0` to it's 0*th* element.

```c
if(strlen(replace)==0)
    replace[0]='\0';
```

However, surprisingly, if the user once replaces something with a *non-empty* replacement , say `"she"` to `"he"` , then if they select a target, say `"Jane"` , and attempt to 'remove' it simply by pressing ENTER when asked for replacement, the *last assigned value* of `replacement[]` is applied ! , so instead of removing `"Jane"`, the user has now replaced it with `"he"` !

It appears that this occurs whenever there is more than one iteration of the replacement loop, basically whenever there *exists* a previously assigned value to revert to.

`char replace[]` is **defined within** the loop, so I don't quite get why this happens, since it does got out of scope and is recreated with every iteration, but perhaps it is not *destroyed* ... Still, this is quite inexplicable to me, and I am fairly new to C so maybe there's something obvious I'm missing.

A look at how variables are declared :

```c
while(...){
        FILE * rep = fopen("...","r");FILE * tmp = fopen("...","w");
        if(rep==NULL||tmp==NULL){
            perror("\n Error "); break;
        }
        else{
            /*
               gets target word and replacement
            */
            if (strlen(target)==0){
                printf("\n Target cannot be blank.\n"); continue;
            if(strlen(replace)==0)
                replace[0]='\0';
            replace(rep,tmp,target,replace); // function which replaces target with replace and writes it all to tmp
            /*
                 Rename/remove+rename tmp as source file + Ask user to quit/continue
            */
            ...
       }
}
```

And how I'm taking input for  `char replace[]` :

```c
char replace[MAX_LN]; lscan(replace);eat();
```

Where :

```c
#define MAX_LN 10000
#define LN_LIM 9999
void eat()
{
    int eat;while ((eat = getchar()) != '\n' && eat != EOF);
}
int lscan(char *line){
    int give = scanf("%9999[^\n]", line);
    return give;
}
```

**EDIT :**

" Just change `char replace[MAX_LN];` to `char replace[MAX_LN] = "";` and it will work. The explanation is that you need to make replace an empty line before reading the input. – [4386427](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4386427/4386427) " Solves this question.

Comment: `if(strlen(replace)==0)  replace[0]='\0';` serves no point.  `strlen(replace)==0` is only true when `replace[0]=='\0'` (or due to UB).

Comment: Show how you're reading the input. Apparently it's not putting an empty string in `replace`.

Comment: This `if(strlen(replace)==0) replace[0]='\0';` does absolutely nothing. `replace[0]` is already `'\0'` The "bug" is in the non-posted input part

Comment: If `replace` is not initialized, reading it is undefined behavior. It's not uncommon for the same memory to be used each iteration, so it will still have whatever was left from the previous iteration.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code that reads the input. As the question is now, we can't help and will therefore have to close your question.

Comment: Inside your loop you probably have code like `char replace[SOME_SIZE];` If so change it to `char replace[SOME_SIZE] = "";` and you should be fine.

Comment: Understood  @4386427 .. I have edited it to show how I read input. I'm not sure what you mean by your second comment there . I think you may now 'reopen' my question.

Comment: Just change `char replace[MAX_LN];` to `char replace[MAX_LN] = "";` and it will work. The explanation is that you need to make `replace` an empty line **before** reading the input.

Comment: With the current code and a user that just press "enter" nothing will be written to `replace` and consequently it's uninitialized (and just happen to hold the same as it did in the previous loop).

Comment: @4386427 It works, I understand, and if you care to post an answer, I'll accept it and upvote it

Comment: @user13863346 I can't reopen it myself. It requires more votes. Remember: When posting question, read the comments and if more code is requested, edit your question. In case it will take several minutes to do the edit, post a comment and tell that you will provide the requested code asap. In that way the risk of getting your question closed is reduced. That is: We typically close if there is no reaction from OP but leave open when OP reacts.

Comment: @4386427 Alrighty, gotcha... I gather reopening isn't so frequent huh ? Well... I'm not in a position to advise patience so...

Comment: Well, patience... There was 17 min between @Barmar requested you to post more code and the closing. I think 17 min should be sufficient for providing the code or at least post a comment saying: Wait, I'll post the code asap.

Comment: @4386427 I concede, I concede and agree.

Comment: `%9999[^\n]` requires at least one character before the newline for it to convert the input and update `line`. That's why you need to check the return value of `scanf()`. Or don't use `scanf()` at all -- read a line with `fgets()` and then use `sscanf()` if you want to parse it.